# Form field validation against list

Tags: php, validation

I would like to validate a form field with a specific data in the list, for example 15 digits. In the code example below, I need help with the code to scan the list for the number. 2 entries below is the example, however the real list will be hundreds of lines.

```
 public function validate($value)
{
    $file_location = '/path/to/file/a1.txt';

    // Mage::log($file_location, null , 'aa.log', 1);

    $allowed_values = explode("\n",trim(file_get_contents($file_location)));
    array_walk($allowed_values, 'trim');
    // $allowed_values = array('');

    return in_array($value, $allowed_values);
}
```

List example

```
C810,34402,BB-H500,356523076903149,TESTE
C810,34402,BB-H500,356523076452163,TESTE
```

Thank you

Comment: So... this code is or is not working? Also it might be wise to change `"\n"` to `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a csv ? Then try

```
public function validate($value)
{
    $file_location = '/path/to/file/a1.txt';

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file_location)); //Get all values from the file
    $allowed_values = array_column(3); // Replace 3 by the index of the field
    return in_array($value, $allowed_values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Exalyon The file is a .txt file not a .csv file.